# Is a c++ dereference an lvalue or an rvalue?

Tags: c++, dereference, bare-metal

I am confident I understand the meaning of `rvalue` and `lvalue`. What's not clear to me is whether a dereference is an `rvalue`.

Consider this:

```
#define GPIO_BASE             0x20200000
#define GPFSEL1               (*(volatile unsigned int *)(AUX_MU_BASE + 0x4))
```

GPFSEL1 is a dereference to an unsigned int pointer.  That unsigned int pointer is a physical address of a hardware register.

I have read that this is a common technique in bare metal programming to access hardware registers directly.  So far I am able to use it with no problem.

Now I want a `reference` to `GPFSEL1` as a member of a struct.  Is this possible?

```
struct MotorControl
{
    u8 pwm_pin;
    u8 ctrla_pin;
    u8 ctrlb_pin;
    volatile unsigned int* MYGPFSEL; // this is not the same thing so does not work
}
```

Given this function below, what's the correct way to reference `GPFSEL1` which is defined elsewhere and how to dereference it to set the its value?

```
MotorContorl group
group.MYGPFSEL = ?
void set(unsigned char pin_number, bool high)
{
if (high)
    {
      // how to correct this statement
      group.MYGPFSEL |= 1<< pin_number;
    } 
}
```

Comment: `C` does not define an rvalue, AFAIR.

Comment: Removed the tag

Comment: This is a little unclear. What does that struct have to do with lvalue vs rvalue?

Comment: Is a dereference its own type? Can I declare a variable as having a type of dereference?

Comment: That's basically what references are. You can use `volatile unsigned int &MYGPFSEL;`.

Comment: A reference member makes the structure somewhat awkward to work with. Why do you want one?

Comment: So I don't hardcore the Motor Class.  There are more than one GPFSEL`N` depending on which `GPIO` pins you want to use

Comment: Have you tried writing what you are suggesting? Did you get any errors?

Comment: @PasserBy Yes, and now currently trying to workout melpomene's suggestion

Comment: Dereferencing an object pointer yields a lvalue object being pointed to by the pointer. References, in all legal contexts, also evaluates to a lvalue object being referenced

Comment: @PasserBy right so how can I now reference that object?

Comment: Just like you would any normal object? By initializing it?

Comment: @SamHammamy Note that in C++ a "reference" is a very specific thing, so make sure that's what you really want (you probably don't, the current code that uses pointers is the normal way to do what you are doing)

Comment: @nos I agree, I was just hoping to re-use it in the struct.

Answer (score 4):

"Dereference" is a verb - you dereference a pointer to get access to the value it points to.

The type conversion is straightforward - if you have a pointer to an integer, and you dereference it, you're now working with an integer. It's an lvalue, as it (by construction) takes up a location in memory, and one that you can (usually) modify.

```
int x = 10;
int* xptr = &x;
*xptr = 5; // *xptr is an lvalue
std::cout << "X: " << x << std::endl; // Prints 5
```

However, the pointer needs to point to a place in memory. If you just start with

```
int* xptr;
*xptr = 5;
```

You're going to get an error, since you're trying to dereference a pointer that doesn't point to a valid memory address. (And if it does, that's purely by coincidence, and you'll incorrectly change the value.)

If you want a reference to GPFSEL1 as a member of your MotorControl struct, you will not be able to initialize the struct without passing it the object to which it will reference. What you probably want instead is a pointer inside the struct, which is much easier to work with:

```
MotorControl myMotorControl;
myMotorControl.MYGPFSEL = GPFSELF1;
```

Comment: The point is that `GPFSEL` is defined else where.  I want a copy of it in the struct.

I can't just do:
`volatile unsigned int * MYGPFSEL = something`

Comment: I've updated my answer. Making a reference inside your struct is probably not what you want, as you'll need to initialize the struct with the value to which the reference will refer. Your struct currently is a pointer, and you can initialize it to point to GPFSEL1

Comment: I think I understand.  Then when I manipulate whatever `MYGPFSEL` points to with a dereference when needed.

Comment: That last sentence should read: "Your struct currently uses a pointer for MYGPFSEL." And yes, you can update whatever MYGPFSEL points to by dereferencing MYGPFSEL and assigning a new value to it.

Comment: Thanks @GraphicsMuncher.  This is what ended compiling for me. `struct X {volatile unsigned int* GPFSEL}` and `this->x.MYGPFSEL = &GPFSEL1` and `*(this->x.GPFSET) |= 1<< pin_number;`  Still unsure if it's correct code.  The testing on bare metal take time :)

Answer (score 1):

Your current approach will work fine, you just need to initialize the member variable appropriately, e.g.

```
struct MotorControl control;
control.MYGPFSEL = (volatile unsigned int *)(AUX_MU_BASE + 0x4);
```

alternatively you can initialize it as

```
control = &GPFSEL1;
```

given that you have defined GPFSEL1 as in your original question:

```
#define GPFSEL1 (*(volatile unsigned int *)(AUX_MU_BASE + 0x4))`
```

Now you can read the register:

```
 foo = *control.MyGPFSEL;
```

or set the register:

```
 *control.MyGPFSEL = 123;
```

Comment: Yes that's true, but `GPFSEL` is defined else where and I was hoping to reuse it

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by that ? Where did you define GPFSEL ? How did you define it ? If you did not want it as a member of your struct, why did you place it there ?

Comment: I have a `gpio.h` file where I keep all GPIO physical addresses.  In there I have.  `#define GPIO_BASE             0x20200000`, and `#define GPFSEL1               (*(volatile u32 *)(GPIO_BASE + 0x4))`, and GPFSEL2, and GPFSEL3, ...

Comment: Then initialize the member with `control.MYGPFSEL = &GPFSEL1 ;`

Comment: This answer is closest to the solution.  If you can please update it to something like: `struct X {volatile unsigned int* GPFSEL}` and `x.MYGPFSEL = &GPFSEL1` and `*(x.GPFSET) |= 1<< pin_number;` or cleaner then I can accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: @SamHammamy I don't understand why I should add `this->x.MYGPFSEL = &GPFSEL1` to this code, there is no info in your question that you have the struct as a member of a class. And how you use your register is entirely up to you - make a function set a pin instead of writing `*(this->x.GPFSET) |= 1<< pin_number;` every time, and drop the `this->`  part too.

Answer (score -2):

This is an easy question to answer, a dereference can be the left-hand side of an assignment so it's an l-value.

Easy case to illustrate:

```
char sz[] {"hello"};
*sz = 'j';
```

If something can be the left side of an assignment it is by definition an l-value.

Comment: That is very flawed reasoning. It could as easily be a reference to the object. It is a lvalue because the standard says so

Comment: *If something can be the left side of an assignment it is by definition an l-value.* ... consider `struct foo {}; foo{} = {};`. I have a prvalue on the left, yet I can assign to it.

Comment: Yeah, it's not a definition of an l-value (considering all the mess the `c++11` made with it's innovations), it is more of a rule of thumb, and it mostly applies to `c` or `c++98`.